# Copy a value from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been googling this to no avail for a day now, I have no doubt that this question has been answered but in contexts that are currently too difficult for me.

I am trying to copy a number from one sheet to another in the same active spreadsheet with the press of a button. 'Character

```
function testing(){
 SpreadsheetApp.openById('testSheet')
    .getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    .getRange('A1')
    .setValue(SpreadsheetApp.openById('testSheet')
        .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
        .getRange('A1')
        .getValue()); 
}
```

When ever I use this to move a simple number over I get the

> Bad Value error.

This is probably a trivial thing so even a link to a tutorial on multi sheet scripting would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Standard practice when debugging is to use multiple statements, to accurately isolate the actual line of code that is failing (when a stack trace is not available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break up your code a bit. This works for me.

```
function testing(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1a1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A1").getValue();
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1").setValue(sheet1a1);
}
```

By the way, I only get the "bad value" error if I use the `SpreadsheetApp.openById('testSheet')` lines. Not sure if you're actually passing `testSheet` or if it's just dummy text, but to be clear, it isn't a valid value to pass to that. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) for what value to pass it.